# QGIS not showing cascading relations in identify

Tags: qgis, relates, identify, relation

I have 3 tables that are related as shown in figure below:
[image]

I added two relaltions. The first one between Table1 and Table2 and the other one between Table2 and Table3 as shown in figure below:

[image]

On Table 1 and Table 2, when I identify, the related records are shown. However, When I want to access Table 3 from Table 1 using Table 2, it doesn't show. As shown in figures below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm wondering if it is a bug, or it has not been implemented. What can I do?